# Ошибки удаления файлов

Tags: php

Из БД выводяться названия фотографий, которые отображаются как input

```
<? foreach ($dataImg as $rows): ?>
  <input name="image[]" value="<?=$rows['image']?>"><br/>
<? endforeach ?>
```

При нажатии на кнопку удалить, названия фотографий помещаются в переменную

`$images = $_POST['image'];`

выглядят вот так:

```
array(6) { 
  [0]=> string(36) "965685735aa0b00fbccbb3e331a6c822.jpg" 
  [1]=> string(36) "82cd1f7e7fd90c0be19aadccdf2961b8.jpg" 
  [2]=>... 
}
```

Далее я пытаюсь перебрать все фото и удалить каждую из директории с нужным названием, но ничего не выходит. Как исправить ситуацию, чтобы все фото удалялись?

```
foreach ($images as $key) {
  $images = $key['image'];
  $filepathI = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/content/products/'.$images;
  unlink($filepathI);
}
```

Ошибки:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'image' in.... on line 26
>
> Warning: unlink(..../content/products/2): No such file or directory

Comment: а права на удаление файла у скрипта есть?

Comment: @Jean-Claude да, по одному я могу удалить

Comment: _Ошибки: Warning: Illegal string offset 'image' in.... on line 26_ Так у Вас выше дамп говорит что $images просто массив картинок... Ваш $key в foreach это уже картинка, а вы $key['image'] непонятный добавляете

Comment: @InDevX не совсем понимаю, что нужно сделать в итоге

Comment: Удалить ненужную переменную $images, и  $filepathI = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/content/products/'.$key;

Comment: @InDevX спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно обращаетесь к значениям массива $images с названиями фотографий.
Нужно переделать цикл следующим образом:

```
foreach ($images as $val) {
    $filepathI = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/content/products/'.$val;
    unlink($filepathI);
}
```